# Does Cauchy's integral theorem work for Riemann Surfaces?

Tags: complex-analysis, riemann-surfaces, cauchy-integral-formula

The way I learned to prove Cauchy's Integral Theorem was by using Green's Theorem and Cauchy-Riemann equations. Now that we're working with Riemann-Surfaces, doing a simple closed curve might not necessary get you back at the same point on the Surface. I've experimented with some functions like $\sqrt{z}$ and $\sqrt[3]{z}$ and figured out if I looped around 2 and 3 times respectively, the integral would be 0. How can I prove it? I'm trying to apply green's theorem, but the nature of the Riemann-Surface makes it hard to comprehend the double integral.

Comment: Looping only one time won't give a closed curve on the underlying Riemann surface $X$. Then $z^{1/2}dz = \frac23 dz^{3/2}$ is an exact 1-form because $z^{3/2}$ is a well-defined function $X\to \Bbb{C}$, so $\int_\gamma z^{1/2}dz = 0$ for any closed curve $\gamma\subset X$.

Comment: Formulated properly, such theorems do exist. What is your proposed formulation?

Comment: @reuns Yes, I'm aware of that. The thing is we know an integral around closed loop is 0 because of Green's Theorem and the Holomorphic conditions. I don't know how to apply them to a surface with branches though.

Comment: $\int_\gamma \phi(u)du = 0$ if $u$ is a chart $U\subset X\to \Bbb{C}$ with $U$ simply connected and $\phi$ is holomorphic in $u$ and $\gamma\subset U$ is a closed loop. There is no such thing as surfaces with branches. $z^{1/2}$ has two branches as a function on $\Bbb{C}$ and we construct the Riemann surface $X$ making it holomorphic $X\to \Bbb{C}$.